# How to get the value of the current scale of InteractiveViewer in flutter?

Tags: flutter

So what I want to do here is to change the size of a SingleChildScrollView proportionally whenever the scale of the InteractiveViewer. For example: scale 1.0 = width of the scrollview is 1000, scale 2.0 = width of the scrollview is 2000 and so on. I can't seem to find out how to be able to do this directly from the documentation. So I considered it by getting the value of the property(scale) itself and re-render the SingleChildScrollView widget but I can't seem to find any way to do this either. If there is any need for more clarification feel free to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onInteractionUpdate` is called when the user updates a pan or scale gesture on the widget. So you can get the current `scale` from the `callback`.

I added a demo code below:

```
       InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: transformationController,
        onInteractionUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details){  // get the scale from the ScaleUpdateDetails callback
          var myScale = details.scale;
          print(myScale); // print the scale here
        },
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 4.6,
        scaleEnabled: true,
        panEnabled: true,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/user_picture.png'),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Thank you your answer solved my question, can I ask a follow up question, is there a way to only execute the function if zooming in/out and not while panning?

Comment: The `interaction` callbacks are called whether an interaction occurs on the widget(pan or scale). If you don't want the widget to be `panned`, you can set the `panEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: I do still want the widget to be pannable but I don't want the interaction to trigger when I pan, is there a way to limit this?

Comment: Like I said, `pan` and `scale` are interactions and these callbacks will be called anytime an interaction occurs on the widget. See docs attached: `The onInteractionUpdate is alled when the user updates a pan or scale gesture on the widget.` @anonymous, I don't think there is a way to go about what you are asking.

Comment: Actually there is. People looking for this can compare the matrix4 before and after the interation and assess if there was just zoom or also a pan, or just a pan, etc.

Answer (score 28):

You can get the actual and persistent scale value like this:

```dart
class InteractiveViewerTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InteractiveViewerTestState createState() => _InteractiveViewerTestState();
}

class _InteractiveViewerTestState extends State<InteractiveViewerTest> {
  TransformationController _transformationController =
      TransformationController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      minScale: 0.5,
      maxScale: 2.0,
      transformationController: _transformationController,
      onInteractionEnd: (details) {
        // Details.scale can give values below 0.5 or above 2.0 and resets to 1
        // Use the Controller Matrix4 to get the correct scale.
        double correctScaleValue = _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the details.scale is relative to the current interaction, so for example if you pinch inwards it will always return a value less than 1 and if you pinch outwards it will return a value greater than zero and this is regardless of the actual scale of the child widget being interacted upon.

Comment: This is great! Forget the approved answer, this the one!

Comment: the scale returns to 1.0 after zooming finished when i add the controller to the interactive viewer how to stop it

Comment: That is exactly what the solution above is fixing. Are you sure you are using `_transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();` to get the scalue value?

Comment: Incredible answer. Using details.scale (or .verticalScale/.horizontalScale) would reset to 1.0 when a pan gesture ended.

Answer (score -1):

Use `onInteractionUpdate` property and get the value from `ScaleUpdateDetails` like:

```
double scale;

InteractiveViewer(
  onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
    scale = details.scale; // This is your scale. 
  },
  child: FlutterLogo(),
);
```

Comment: curious question, does the word "details" is always used for all widget? for example if I want the height of a container I can do the same thing but change it to details.height?